# MongoDB SetDefaultValue is not working - why?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mapping

I'm using C# and mongodb official driver. I have a problem when using BsonClassMap class to map my entity. Here is some sample code:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Article>(cm =>
{
      cm.AutoMap();
      cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Title).SetElementName("title").SetDefaultValue("abc");
}
```

When I save it to db, I always get a null value in the title field, not the expected "abc". I've tried enum type and get the same problem - where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value is used during deserialization to assign a value to a field or property IF the document being deserialized doesn't have a value for that field or property.

If you create an object in memory with a null value for the Title property then a null will be stored in the database. Just because Title is null doesn't mean it's going to be replaced with the default value when the document is saved.

Comment: thank you so much, you are right. before deserialization I just remove the "title" field from db, then i got the lovely "abc",  I was a little confused by the official tutorial, in "Default values" section, it prints serialization, :) , of course I 'm newbie, thank you for your answser.